# Converse of Ramanujan's Congruences

Tags: elementary-number-theory, integer-partitions

Of Ramanujan's famous congruences for the partition function, $p(5k+4)\equiv0\mod 5$, $p(7k+5)\equiv0\mod7$, and so on, does the converse also hold? For example, if $p(n)\equiv0\mod5$, does that mean $n=5k+4$ for some $k$? If so, does this also hold for the other Ramanujan-style congruences, such as those relating to powers of primes?

Comment: $p\left(7\right) \equiv 0 \mod 5$ but $7 \not\equiv 4 \mod 5$.

Answer (score 2):

No.  For example, $p(7) = 15$ and $p(10) = 42$.